# Does new File("...") lock the file?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-io

I read that `new File("path")` doesn't physically create a file on disk. Though in the API it is said:

> Instances of this class may or may not denote an actual file-system
>   object such as a file or a directory. If it does denote such an object then that object resides in a partition. A partition is an operating system-specific portion of storage for a file system. A single storage device (e.g. a physical disk-drive, flash memory, CD-ROM) may contain multiple partitions.

So I'm curious if it is safe to have such code in multithreaded environment:

```
File file = new File( "myfile.zip" );
// do some operations with file (fill it with content)
file.saveSomewhere(); // just to denote that I save it after several operations
```

For example, thread1 comes here, creates an instance and starts doing operations. Meanwhile thread2 interrupts it, creates its instance *with the same name* (myfile.zip) and does some other operations. After that they consequently save the file.

I need to be sure that they don't work with the same file and the last thread saving the file overwrites the previous one.

Comment: Your question is confusing - do you want the last thread to overwrite the file or not?

Comment: I just need the changes from ONE thread only to be applied. This means I don't want to have a file, where the first half is created by the first thread and the second half is created by the second thread.

Comment: The File is thread safe, but the file operations you mention won't be using a `File` object and they are not thread safe.

Comment: But what will they use then?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: The `File` instance *is* thread-safe, but that's not what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, File does not keep a lock and is not safe for the pattern you describe. You should either lock or keep the file in some wrapper class.

If you would provide a little bit more of your code, somebody can certainly help you find a suitable pattern.

Comment: Or I can give files unique names, like `File file = new File("myfile-" + uniqueId + ".zip");`, right?

Comment: Yes, if that is an option, it is certainly a simple and safe solution.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the lines you commented will not thread-safe, you will have to protect them with a mutex or a monitor. The gold rule is: every time you have to write on something in a multithread context, it's necessary to protect that region to grant the thread-safeness (Bernstein conditions).

I'm not sure if the statement you propose requires to be protected too as i never used that command, but i thought this could be helpful to someone else too.